# How i can write c_ numpy list to txt file?

Tags: python, list, numpy, parsing

I'm making a parser for site.From site i took info (Name of manga, author, genres).
It's all i added to c_ list

```
        api = requests.get(f'https://henchan.pro/manga/new?offset={page_count}')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(api.content, 'lxml')
        title = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class": 'title_link'})]
        href = [e['href'] for e in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class": 'title_link'})]
        author = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={"class": 'item2'})]
        original_work = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={"class": 'original work'})]
        genres = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": 'genre'})]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    page_count += 20
    _all = c_[title, href, author, original_work, genres]
```

At the output, i get: https://prnt.sc/u2buv6

How can I record all this in the same form in a TXT file?

P.S All my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from numpy import c_
import os

def get_manga():
    page_count = 0
    pages = int(input('Lead the number of pages: '))
    for e in range(pages):
        try:
            api = requests.get(f'https://henchan.pro/manga/new?offset={page_count}')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(api.content, 'lxml')
            title = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class": 'title_link'})]
            href = [e['href'] for e in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class": 'title_link'})]
            author = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={"class": 'item2'})]
            original_work = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={"class": 'original work'})]
            genres = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": 'genre'})]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        page_count += 20
        _all = c_[title, href, author, original_work, genres]
        for x in _all:
            print(f"Title: {x[0]}\nLink: https://henchan.pro/manga{x[1]}\nAuthor: {x[2]}\nOriginal Work: {x[3]}\nGenres: {x[4]}\n")
```

get_manga()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code in your OP with a file output instead of the print.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from numpy import c_
import os

def get_manga():
    with open("filename_goes_here.txt", 'w') as out_file:
        page_count = 0
        pages = int(input('Lead the number of pages: '))
        for e in range(pages):
            try:
                api = requests.get(f'https://henchan.pro/manga/new?offset={page_count}')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(api.content, 'lxml')
                title = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class": 'title_link'})]
                href = [e['href'] for e in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class": 'title_link'})]
                author = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={"class": 'item2'})]
                original_work = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={"class": 'original work'})]
                genres = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": 'genre'})]
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            page_count += 20
        _all = c_[title, href, author, original_work, genres]
            for x in _all:
                out_file.write(f"Title: {x[0]}\nLink: https://henchan.pro/manga{x[1]}\nAuthor: {x[2]}\nOriginal Work: {x[3]}\nGenres: {x[4]}\n"))

get_manga()
```

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't I don't have reputation

Comment: @Mad Physicist
I'm found where it is)